# Ligação de Base de Dados com Php

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados

Boas,

Alguém que perceba de php e um pouco de base de dados que me possa ajudar?

Não consigo fazer ligação da base de dados ao website com php.

Comment: poste seu codigo amigo, se voce disse que não está conseguindo e quer ajuda, poste o código

Comment: Amigo, poste o código é exatamente aonde não consegue progredir, até pq existe diversas formas de se conectar ao banco de dados, qual banco está utilizando ?